# Audits on Route53?

Tags: amazon-route53

Can you perform audits on Route53 to see what was changed in the DNS records? Can you block access to route53 using IAM? 
I ask this because it wasn't possible a year ago.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you perform audits on Route53 to see what was changed in the DNS records?

If you mean **who changed what**, you can use

**Cloudtrail** (it logs everything from all AWS services): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html

**AWS Config**: https://aws.amazon.com/config/

If you just want to **check what changed** you can run tests using either:

**AWS CLI or Console**: https://www.cloudconformity.com/conformity-rules/Route53/sender-policy-framework-record-present.html

**CLI53 Tool**: https://github.com/barnybug/cli53

Comment: Suggest you add AWS Config to your answer : https://aws.amazon.com/config/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can provide an IAM policy that excludes Route53.

No, I'm not aware of any built-in auditing. You could, though, set something up via the APIs to periodically export your records and audit changes on your end.